# Create a menu item with subitems

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

How can I create a menu link for `main-menu` which has related subitems?

For example in main-menu I have Home  About  Products and for the Products menu item I want it to put all categories as subitems: Products -> Shoes -> Shirts ...

Is there a hook or an example so you can achieve this?

Comment: plz expand details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a menu programatically through menu hooks, and a great source for sample code and explanation is the menu_example portion of the [Examples Module](http://drupal.org/project/examples). You can also set up new menu items and strcutre through Drupal's admin menus management (admin/structure/menus)

Answer (score 0):

In Your exaple You can use [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module ;) It transform taxonomy vocabularies structure into menu tree.

But if You want to do this programmatically (but why?) the best way is to look at [Example Module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) or [other implementations of hook_menu](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/implementations/hook_menu/7) and creating your own module.

Answer (score -1):

Why you want to do it programmatically? You can use GUI for it and use Superfish or similar module to display drop down menu and subitems?

Comment: I want to create it programmatically because I have multiple instances and I don't want to use GUI every time I add a new menu item.

Comment: Doesn't matter why. Thats the question. There are myriad reasons why programatically is the only option. Consider these questions as comments and not answers in future.